# How Can i Deal with Ping Exception in c#

Tags: c#, exception, ping

I've created a simple method to check if my Internet connection is active. Unfortunately, the try section becomes overlooked because of System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException” in System.Net.Ping.dll. As well noticed, the problem occurs with PingReply. 
Could you tell me how to deal with this excepion and allow code to run correctly so to execute try section.

MyFunction:

```
    private void ConnectionStatusChecker(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        Ping myPing = new Ping();
        String host = "https://www.google.com/";
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
        int timeout = 1000;
        PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions();

        Ping ping = new Ping();
        try
        {
            PingReply reply = myPing.Send(host, timeout, buffer, pingOptions);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                ConnectionStatus = "Connected";
            else
                ConnectionStatus = "Disconnected";
        }
        catch (System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException)
        {
            ConnectionStatus = "Disconnected-Exception";
        }
    }
```

Edit: I would like to store in ConnectionStatus Variable the information about my Internet Connection. Try section describes the value in case of beeing disconnected or connected. But PingException does not allow me to check it - exception automatically blocks try section. The thing is, how to deal with this exception, where is the source or mistake I made?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Could you try to clarify a little bit more?

Comment: I have just added a small explanation

Comment: The exception will trigger if [`Ping.Send `](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.send?view=netframework-4.8) fails with `System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: But why it fails if I have Connection and google server is valid?

Comment: @Matheew Check to see if the `PingException` has an `InnerException`. It'll probably tell you the reason why it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should log `InnerException` to see whats really going on:

```
catch (PingException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
    ConnectionStatus = "Disconnected-Exception";
}
```

Which outputs the following output:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.GetAddressAndSend(String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout, Byte[] buffer, PingOptions options)
```

And fails for the `ping` command as well(making sure the results are expected):

```
PS C:\Users\user> ping https://www.google.com/
Ping request could not find host https://www.google.com/. Please check the name and try again.
```

Which means that the host `https://www.google.com/` is not enabling ICMP replies for HTTPS. You can have a look at [Can you get a reply from a HTTPS site using the Ping command?](https://superuser.com/questions/326403/can-you-get-a-reply-from-a-https-site-using-the-ping-command) for a good explanation as to why this is happening.

You can also verify this in [`System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.send?view=netframework-4.8) documentation:

> **PingException**
>
> An exception was thrown while sending or receiving the ICMP messages. See the inner exception for the exact exception that was thrown.

Instead, try to ping the hostname `www.google.com`:

```
Ping myPing = new Ping();
String host = "www.google.com";
byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
int timeout = 1000;
PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions();

string ConnectionStatus;

Ping ping = new Ping();
try
{
    PingReply reply = myPing.Send(host, timeout, buffer, pingOptions);
    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        ConnectionStatus = "Connected";
    else
        ConnectionStatus = "Disconnected";
    }
catch (PingException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
    ConnectionStatus = "Disconnected-Exception";
}

Console.WriteLine(ConnectionStatus);
```

Which outputs no exceptions and the connection succeeds:

```
Connected
```