# C# tread sleep inside timer tick

Tags: c#, timer, sleep

I make an HTTP request inside the timer tick.
Typically. the HTTP response comes after the tick is over.
So, the response is handled in the next tick which is late.

I added some code to check for the response and if it is not there adding a thread sleep to the tick code.
I notice that the thread sleep does happen but even though the sleep length is enough the response still comes when the tick is over.

In other words, the HTTP response does not take advantage of timer tick sleeping.
How can I ensure that the HTTP response takes advantage of the tick code sleeping to complete before the tick is over.

Comment: Could you please provide some code to make your question clearer?

Comment: Maybe you can `await` the response?

Comment: Does [Best way to check a url every second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72900377/5438626) help answer your question?